# WordPress website validation

Tags: php, wordpress, validation

I'm trying to validate an URL in WordPress, But it's not working. what I want to do is just that, when someone insert something without the http at the beginning it give's you an error message. can you help me with that? here is my code:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

//adding the meta box fields
function team_web_field() {
    add_meta_box( 'custom-team-web', __( 'Website' ), 'team_show_website', 'team', 'normal', 'low' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'team_web_field' );

// HTML for the admin area
function team_show_website() {
    global $post;
    $website = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'website', true );

        //validating!
    if ( ! preg_match( "/http(s?):\/\//", $website ) && $website != "") {
        $errors = "This URL isn't valid";
        $website = "http://";

    } 

    // output invalid url message and add the http:// to the input field
    if( isset($errors) ) { echo sanitize_text_field($errors); }

    ?>  
    <p>
        <label for="team_website">
                <input id="team_website" size="55" name="team_website" value="<?php if( isset($website) ) { echo $website; } ?>" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <?php
}

//saving custom field data
function team_website_save( $post_id ) {
    global $post;   

    if( isset($_POST['team_website'])) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'website', esc_url_raw($_POST['team_website']) );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'team_website_save' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `esc_url_raw` causes the website to be an empty string because the protocol is invalid and thus, the `$website != ""` condition is false.

From the [WordPress documentation on esc_url_raw](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url_raw):

> An empty string is returned if $url specifies a protocol other than those in $protocols, or if $url contains an empty string.

Also, your regex is a match no matter where `http://` is in the string. You may want to change it to `/^http(s?):\/\//` and possibly to do a case-insensitive check.